# Inserting into mysql database with asian symbols such as ’ —

Tags: php, mysql

I cant seem to get these Chinese punctuation marks to work with my database (utf-8)
when i do an echo of the query the marks look like this
���

in php i have already done

$text=mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($text));

so as a result they are not saved into the database correctly what can i do to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Executing mysql_query('SET NAMES utf-8'); before any operations with unicode will do the trick

Answer (score 1):

Try using using `utf8_encode()` function while inserting into db and `utf8_decode()` while printing the same.

Answer (score 0):

Add the character 'N' before your string value.

Eg. select from test_table where temp=N'unicode string'

Answer (score 0):

besides if you want to use htmlentities, you have to set it to utf-8 encoding like that:

```
htmlentities($string,ENT_COMPAT,"UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't put HTML-encoded data in the database. It should be raw text until the time you spit it onto the page (at which point you should use `htmlspecialchars()`.

You need to make sure that both your database and your page are using UTF-8:

- ensure your tables are CREATEd with a UTF-8 collation;
- use [mysql_set_charset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php) after connecting to ensure the connection between MySQL and PHP is UTF-8;
- set the `Content-Type` of the page to `text/html;charset=utf-8` by header or meta tag.

You can get away with using a different encoding such as the default latin-1 on the database end and the connection if you treat it as bytes, but case-insensitive comparisons won't work if you do, so it's best to stick to UTF-8.